# Android Geocoder returns an empty array as a response on Unit Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, robolectric, google-geocoder

I have implemented some unit tests using:

```
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
testImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.8"
```

Here is the Unit Test code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class NetworkAddressDataSourceTest {

    @Test
    fun test_1(): Unit = runBlocking {
        val context = getApplicationContext<Context>()
        val networkAddressDataSource = NetworkAddressDataSource(context)

        // Expected address = "San Jose, US"
        val hex = Hex("", arrayOf(), Location(37.28546527, -121.8749344))

        networkAddressDataSource.getLocationAddress(hex).map {
            assert(it == "San Jose, US")
        }
        Unit
    }
}
```

And here is `getLocationAddress(hex: Hex)` function:

```
override suspend fun getLocationAddress(hex: Hex): Either<Failure, String?> {
    return if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
        val geocoderAddress =
            Geocoder(context).getFromLocation(hex.center.lat, hex.center.lon, 1)[0]

        Either.Right(
            if (geocoderAddress.locality != null) {
                "${geocoderAddress.locality}, ${geocoderAddress.countryCode}"
            } else if (geocoderAddress.subAdminArea != null) {
                "${geocoderAddress.subAdminArea}, ${geocoderAddress.countryCode}"
            } else if (geocoderAddress.adminArea != null) {
                "${geocoderAddress.adminArea}, ${geocoderAddress.countryCode}"
            } else {
                geocoderAddress.countryName
            }
        )
    } else {
        Either.Left(Failure.NoGeocoderError)
    }
}
```

The issue is that:

```
val geocoderAddress = Geocoder(context).getFromLocation(hex.center.lat, hex.center.lon, 1)
```

Always returns an empty array as a response. How should I fix this? Does this happen because these tests are local unit tests so the only real solution here is to change to instrumented tests?

Is there a workaround?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why are you testing a third party dependency ? usually i think the idea is to assume that a third party dependency (whether from google or from a library) works, we make use of unit tests to test our logic and integration essentially

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have had some issues on reverse geocoding and would like to create some testing not only to verify the results, but also have an easy way to check if for some reason the results are different, to have knowledge of it in an easy way.

Comment: yeah i understand, i'm not sure if that would be possible though, if it depends on an api call being done i'm not sure you'll ever be able to get consistent results for this